# Proof for the following limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

what is the proof of the limit of $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\neq1\\-2
&x=1\end{cases}$$ at $x=1$?

I have attempted to prove this with the $\delta\text{-}\epsilon$ definition but have not been successful.

$$\forall\epsilon>0\space\exists\delta>0\,\text{s.t.}\space \forall x,\\0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\\|x-1|<\epsilon=\delta\\0<|x-1|<\delta\ \quad \blacksquare$$

Comment: Why have you been not successful? please show your attempt

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I have added my attempt to my question

Comment: Can you tell me what is your doubt? You assumed that the limit is $1$ and now you want to prove it. You need to show that for all $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that when $0<|x-1|<\delta,|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$. So we want to find a $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. Note that $|f(x)-1|=|x-1|<\delta$, so if we choose a $\delta\le\epsilon$, we will ensure $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$....

Comment: @ShubhamJohri So am I correct? I was told to have another look at my attempt but was not sure why so that is why I asked here.

Comment: From the way you have written your answer, I am not sure you fully understood what you were writing. For example, why have you written $|x-1|<\delta$ at the end? But notwithstanding that, it is correct since you have taken $\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I was rewriting $|x-a|<\delta$ but having taken $\delta\space\text{to be equal to}\space\epsilon$

Comment: That's fine, any $\delta\le\epsilon$ will do

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall\epsilon:0<|x-1|<\delta=\epsilon\implies|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$$ is a true statement. You can conclude.

---

Also ponder that

$$\forall\epsilon:|x-1|<\delta=\epsilon\implies|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$$ is a false statement.

Comment: Because of the deleted neighbourhood?

Comment: @MrMath: mh, what do you mean exactly ?